# Is there a GIS to locate exact opposite locations on earth?

Tags: geolocation

I was wandering if there was a GIS that offers to locate the exact opposite location of key locations (countries, even cities ?) on earth ?

Comment: The opposite of a location at (lambda, phi) is at (180+lambda, -phi) (where lambda is longitude and phi is latitude in degrees).  What additional help in "location" would you like from the GIS?

Comment: You can do this with QGIS, see: https://gis.stackexchange.com/a/383290/88814

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Something like https://web.archive.org/web/20120512014755/http://www.antipodemap.com/?

Edited: original site does not exist anymore but still works in Wayback Machine

Comment: This is what I was looking for, but Kirk's answer will be useful as well. Thanks to all of you !

Answer (score 9):

[image: Antipodes]

This seems trivial to me, yet wikipedia's article on [Antipodes](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Antipodes) goes into a lot of detail.

Comment: does this map hold at higher latitudes?

Comment: @iant It looks like someone simply took a copy of the existing world coastlines applied the simple formula mentioned by @huber, and then added it as a layer on top of the original.  A more interesting question to me is "Are there any practical uses of an antipodal map?".

Comment: Working out where the core of a nuclear reactor  ends up if it melts (China Syndrome).